# prove the definition of limits of function

Tags: real-analysis

Let a ∈ R and let f be a real-valued function defined J \ {a} where J is an open interval containing a.
Also, let L ∈ R. Then
limx→a
f(x) = L
if and only if for all  > 0 there exists δ > 0 such that
|f(x) − L| <  whenever 0 < |x − a| < δ
for x ∈ J

I was trying to prove this theorem, but I just used "f is continuous at a iff limf(x)=f(a)=L". Is it correct?

Comment: What is your definition of limit of a function? Do you use sequences as definition? Because then I would use that and contradiction.

Comment: how to use contradiction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what definition you are using, because what you have to prove is what I have learned as the definition. So I'm only assuming that the definition you're working with is the following: the limit of function in a point $a$ is $L$ iff for each sequence $(x_n)$ in $J\setminus\{a\} $ with limit $a$ we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$.

So what I would do is assume that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$, yet there exists $\epsilon>0$, such that for each $\delta>0$, we have that $0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta$ and yet $\vert f(x)-f(a)\vert\geq\epsilon$. Now what kind of sequence can you construct with this? We can consider the sequence $(x_n)$ in $J\setminus\{a\}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, it holds that $0<\vert x_n-a\vert<\frac{1}{n}$. (Why can we do this?) From there on it is possible to derive a contradiction. (Note: this only proves the "$\implies$" direction!)